# Less than 50 respondents in another study indicated that Sun exposure affected the chances of getting Cancer

Tags: synonyms

Statement: >***Less*** than 50 respondents in another study indicated that Sun exposure affected the chances of getting Cancer.

Should I replace the word **Less** with *fewer* or *smaller* or *lower* or *lesser* or should I keep it as it is?

Comment: Sorry, have to question that **respondents indicated** the connection between sun exposure and cancer? Respondents now draw study conclusions?

Comment: c'mon - it's a number less than 50 - just tell us the number for Pete's sake.